# Cocos2D iPhone - running actions on multiple targets + callback

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have an array of objects (objArray) and an array of actions (actArray). Both arrays are in order, I mean, object at index 0 of objArray has to perform action 0 on actArray.

To make the explanation clear, lets imagine both arrays have 3 objects, obj0, obj1 and obj2.

```
obj0 has to perform action 0 on actArray
obj1 has to perform action 1 on actArray
obj2 has to perform action 2 on actArray
```

these 3 operations (or n, in the case of the array) have to happen simultaneously.

**When all animations end, I need the method animationsFinished to be called.**

How do I do that?

I am beginning in Cocos. I have googled around and have not found any practical example around. I have found CCSpan but I don't see how this can be used with multiple objects each one with its own action. thanks.

Comment: Is that a typo that you want action 2 to be called on obj1? Should that be action 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just perform the actions sequentially and they will occur at the same time.

```
int yourAnimationDuration; //this needs to be set to whatever your animation speed is
for(int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++) {
    [[objArray objectAtIndex:idx] runAction:[actArray objectAtIndex:idx]];
    [self performSelector:@selector(someMethodToBeExecutedWhenAnimationFinishes) withObject:nil afterDelay:yourAnimationDuration];
}
```

Or if you want the animation-is-finished method to be executed only once, just take it out of the for loop.

Edit:

```
id finalAnimation = [CCSequence actionOne:[actArray objectAtIndex:idx] two:someMethod];
```

This (I believe) will execute your method once the first action is completed.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about a callback mechanism, but I think this will be the best option. Thanks

Comment: As for `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` - it would be better to avoid this, because cocos2d has its own scheduler (with ability to pause/resume).

Answer (score 1):

In above case you mentioned , someMethodToBeExecutedWhenAnimationFinishes will be executed three times. Just use it 1 time after the loop.
'yourAnimationDuration' will be time of the action with maximum duration as all other actions must have ended before the one with maximum duration.

'CCSequence' is a good option but you need to perform CCSequence only with the action with maximum duration instead of all of the objects.

So In 1st case

```
int yourAnimationDuration; //this needs to be set to duration of action with maximum time
for(int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++) {
    [[objArray objectAtIndex:idx] runAction:[actArray objectAtIndex:idx]];
}
 [self performSelector:@selector(someMethodToBeExecutedWhenAnimationFinishes) withObject:nil afterDelay:yourAnimationDuration];
```

In 2nd Case
Suppose if your 2nd action takes maximum time.

```
int actionNum = 2;
for(int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++) {
   if(idx == (actionNum-1))
{
[[objArray objectAtIndex:idx] runAction:[CCSequence actions:[actArray objectAtIndex:idx],[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(someMethodToBeExecutedWhenAnimationFinishes:)],nil];
}
else{
 [[objArray objectAtIndex:idx] runAction:[actArray objectAtIndex:idx]];
}
}
```

Hope that helps. I have not run this code. So check for syntax if any. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need this code for running Multiple `CCAction` ( **each action for a different CCNode/CCSprite/...** ) ; But starting All **in sequence** !

```
CCMoveBy *moveUpAction = CCMoveBy::create(0.5,ccp(0,400));
CCMoveBy *moveRightAction = CCMoveBy::create(1,ccp(300,0));
CCMoveBy *moveDownAction = CCMoveBy::create(1,ccp(0,-400));

CCTargetedAction *mm = CCTargetedAction::create(someNode_1,moveUpAction);
CCTargetedAction *rr = CCTargetedAction::create(someNode_2,moveRightAction);
CCTargetedAction *dd = CCTargetedAction::create(someNode_3,moveDownAction);

// Here we first run 'moveUpAction' on someNode_1.
// After finishing that Action we start 'moveRightAction' on someNode_2
// After finishing the Action, we start ...
CCSequence *targetedSeq = CCSequence::create(mm,rr,dd,NULL);
whateverNode->runAction(targetedSeq );
```